# Intellij / Flex 4.91 Compilation issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, compilation, intellij-idea

Intellij/ Flex SDK 4.9.1 / Compile 
I am trying to upgrade to 4.9.1 sdk 
I get error saying.

Flex SDK 4.9.1 is not supported by built-in compiler shell. Please change compiler at File | Settings | Compiler | Flex Compiler.

I changed the compiler to use "Mxmlc/compc" rather than the default option in intellij to use "Built-in compiler shell"

This is causing another compile issue 
Now it errors 
" Invalid version specified, ''"

I presume that this is something to do with player version .

Any help in this regards will be appriciated.

Comment: I'm using Flex 4.9.1 with default settings in IntelliJ 12 without a hickup. I think you'll have to provide more extensive information.

Comment: What is your IntelliJ IDEA version? There shouldn't be any problems with 11.1.5 or 12.x. Have you installed official Apache Flex SDK 4.9.1 using their installer?

Comment: Did u use the sdk with air packaged or did u use a standalone version ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is resolved now  ..
The version of sdk i was using didnt have Air packaged in it ...

Downloaded the packaged version ..
It works now !!